# binary search tree vs sorted doubly linked list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I'm wondering, is there any difference between performance of those, provided binary search is used for sorted linked list insertion, search. And in which situations they perform differently or maybe for which purposes, say, list will be unusable or vice versa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do a binary search on a linked list (single or double) simply because there's no way to get to the middle of the list without traversing half of it (from one end).

There's no doubt a form of *multi-level skip list* that will do that but it seems to me that's just emulating a binary tree with a more complex structure.

A sorted linked list tends to be O(n) for search, insertion and deletion (the actual insertion /deletion itself is O(1) but you still have to *find* the insertion or deletion point first).

Alternatively, binary trees (balanced ones) are O(log n) for search, insertion and deletion (all these operations are proportional to the *height* of the tree).

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, for linked list the problem will be that an overhead will be added on each move to the current middle element while performing binary search, right? So, complexity of binary search will be logn * logn instead of logn, right?

Comment: @dhblah, yes, that's correct, the overhead bit at least. Whether it's (log N)^2, I'm not sure, but it's certainly worse than log N.

Comment: @dhblah The cost of one move to the middle is O(n), if your current "interval of interest" has length n. As you progress through binary search, the interval of interest halves in length for every iteration, so the total for all iterations still sums up to O(n). However, the constant is substantially worse than for linear search. Simply put, I cannot think of any reason why binary search would be preferable to linear search for linked lists.